# Eslint and prettier conflict on operator-linebreak rule

Tags: reactjs, eslint, conflict, rules, prettier

I have some eslint and prettier config. When I hit ctrl + s to save my code my eslint is trying to format the code like this :

```
        (errors.password
            && (errors.password.type === 'minLength'
            || errors.password.type === 'maxLength') && (
              <Styled.Error className="invalidForm">
                Password must be more than 6 and less then 32 digits
              </Styled.Error>
          ))
            || (errors.password && (
              <Styled.Error className="invalidForm">
                Password is required
              </Styled.Error>
            ))
```

and instantly after that prettier also format code to that:

```
        (errors.password &&
            (errors.password.type === 'minLength' ||
              errors.password.type === 'maxLength') && (
              <Styled.Error className="invalidForm">
                Password must be more than 6 and less then 32 digits
              </Styled.Error>
            )) ||
            (errors.password && (
              <Styled.Error className="invalidForm">
                Password is required
              </Styled.Error>
            ))
```

I don't want to chage eslint rule, and I don't want to disable prettier format. How could I change the prettier rule for placing logic operators?

Comment: Have you found a solution to bring those logical operators before the expression?

Comment: Nah, the issue is still opened

Answer (score 4):

According to prettier [doc](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html):

> Prettier has a few options because of history. But we don’t want more of them.
> *Prettier is not a kitchen-sink code formatter that attempts to print your code in any way you wish*. It is *opinionated*.

> Quoting the [Why Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/why-prettier.html)? page:
> By far the biggest reason for adopting Prettier is to stop all the on-going debates over styles.

Prettier ships with a handful of format [options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html), some of them are:

- Tab Width
- Tabs
- Semicolons
- Quotes
- Quote Props
- JSX Quotes
- Trailing Commas

But these options doesn't include what you are looking for.

Comment: This config will disable eslint rules, but I need to keep eslint rules and disable prettier rules

Comment: I have updated the answer to show it can't be done.

Comment: There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3806

Comment: I've had the same issue with prettier and eslint conflicting on operator-linebreak. Added prettier in my .eslintrc file's extends array, now eslint is aware of prettier formatting and doesn't throw error.

Comment: it works when prettier is added to .eslintrc file's extends array. Thanks @Rishabh

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by adding the rules from `eslint-config-prettier`.

In my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ["airbnb-base", "prettier"],
  //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid conflicts between ESLint and Prettier, you can use the `eslint-config-prettier` package. This package disables all ESLint rules that are unnecessary or might conflict with Prettier formatting. Here's how you can set it up:

Make sure you have ESLint and Prettier installed in your project. If not, you can install them using npm or yarn.

1. Install package

   `npm install eslint-config-prettier --save-dev`
2. Add prettier to eslintrc config

   `extends: [ 'prettier', // Add this line ],`
3. eslint-config-perttier ships with little CLI tool to help you check your config contains any rules that are unnecessary or conflict with Prettier. To run it

   `npx eslint-config-prettier path/to/main.js`