# Prettier is not respecting self closing jsx tags

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

In my React project, I need prettier to put each prop/attribute of a jsx component onto a separate line.

If I type this:

```
<Animal type="fish" size="small"/>
```

I want prettier to change it to this:

```
<Animal
  type="fish"
  size="small"
/>
```

But it is actually forcing everything onto one line. How do I make prettier put each attribute on one line?

I haven't changed any of the default prettier settings, and prettier is the only code formatting extension I have installed.

Thank you

Comment: Prettier doesn't work that way, you can't force it to format code as you want. It is opinionated so there are only few things you can change like using double quotes or single quote and some other options. You can see the documentation for that. It will make the code look like what you described if it doesn't fit in a single line.

Comment: Hmmm I find it hard to believe that the worlds most popular code formatter for the worlds most popular code editor doesn’t support the worlds most popular syntax for the worlds most popular  front end language

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952854/4901118 this answer may not be for what you are asking but it may be helpful.

Comment: Hard to believe? maybe but that's what documentation are for. Check the documentation to know why it does what is does and what options it provides.

Comment: Yeah I read the documentation

Comment: Try to modify  the setting `prettier.printWidth` with values less than 80, until you get the behavior expected